# Fortran coarray anomaly with co_reduce

Tags: gcc, parallel-processing, fortran, gfortran

The standard example for the `co_reduce` command (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CO_005fREDUCE.html#CO_005fREDUCE)  doesn't seem to work. Running the example with `np` processors should return a `Product value` of `np`!. The value for the first image is corrupted in a seemingly random way:

```
 18:10 rditldmt $ caf co_reduce_example.f08 -o co_reduce_example
 18:10 rditldmt $ cafrun -np 4 ./co_reduce_example
Number of images = 4
value [ 1 ] is 1690042368
value [ 2 ] is 2
value [ 3 ] is 3
value [ 4 ] is 4
Product  value = 1690042368
Expected value = num_images()!
 2! = 2, 3! = 6, 4! = 24, ...
```

With `np = 4`, the expected answer = 24; computed answer = 1690042368.

An instrumented version of the example, `co_reduce_example.f08`, follows:

```
program co_reduce_example

implicit none
integer :: value[ * ]
integer :: k
    value = this_image ( )
    call co_reduce ( value, result_image = 1, operator = myProd )
    if ( this_image ( ) == 1 ) then
        write ( * , '( "Number of images = ", g0 )' ) num_images ( )
        do k = 1, num_images ( )
            write ( * , '( 2( a, i0 ) )' ) 'value [ ', k, ' ] is ', value [ k ]
        end do
        write ( * , '( "Product  value = ", g0 )' ) value  ! prints num_images() factorial
        write ( * , 100 )
    end if
100 format ( "Expected value = num_images()!", /, " 2! = 2, 3! = 6, 4! = 24, ..." )

contains

    pure function myProd ( a, b ) result ( rslt )
        integer, value :: a, b
        integer        :: rslt
            rslt = a * b
        end function myProd

end program co_reduce_example
```

**How do I correct the code?**

Coarray Fortran version:

```
 17:50 rditldmt $ cafrun -v

OpenCoarrays Coarray Fortran Executable Launcher (caf version 1.3.6)
Copyright (C) 2015-2016 Sourcery, Inc.

OpenCoarrays comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute copies of OpenCoarrays under the terms of the
BSD 3-Clause License.  For more information about these matters, see
the file named LICENSE.
```

Gfortran version:

```
 17:54 rditldmt $ gfortran -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.0.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15
Configured with: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc6/gcc6/work/gcc-6-20160327/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin15 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,lto,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc6 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc6 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-6 --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-6 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc6/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-isl=/opt/local --enable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --with-pkgversion='MacPorts gcc6 6-20160327_0'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.0.0 20160327 (experimental) (MacPorts gcc6 6-20160327_0)
```

Comment: You are testing the bleeding edge. Even the Cray compiler doesn't support this. I wouldn't be surprised if there were bugs in the OpenCoarray and gfortran implementation. You should probably open an issue at  https://github.com/sourceryinstitute/opencoarrays/issues and you are very likely to get a response from the most knowledgeable people you can get.

Comment: @VladimirF: Good idea. https://github.com/sourceryinstitute/opencoarrays/issues/172

Answer (score 1):

Edited again:

You are correct, this is a bug in GFortran and/or OpenCoarrays and NOT your code. Follow along at: https://github.com/sourceryinstitute/opencoarrays/issues/172

We are adding @dantopa's code to our regression tests and hope to have this issue resolved before the 7.x release of GFortran... I'll try to remember to update this issue once it has been fixed.

As a work around, replace the `value` attribute with `intent(in)`

---

<s>The problem is resolved by changing the `value` attribute to `intent(in)` for the `pure function myProd()`. I'm not sure if this is a bug in GFortran's implementation and/or handling of the `value` attribute, and IMO the compiler should have issued a warning/error (at least by my reading of "Modern Fortran Explained" by MRC, pp 117, ii) 'the intent of a dummy argument must be declared unless it is a procedure or a pointer, and this intent must be `in` in the case of a function'). Furthermore, the GFortran example for co_reduce needs to be fixed.</s>

Comment: "C1276 The specification-part of a pure function subprogram shall specify that all its nonpointer dummy data objects have the INTENT (IN) **or the VALUE attribute**." Maybe co_reduce has other requirements, but value  is legal for pure procedures.